# IBAction not being called

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ibaction

I am building an app with interface builder for the iPad. The scroll view takes up most of the screen except for a small portion at the bottom. Scrolling is enabled downwards. In the small portion on the bottom (not inside the scrollview), there is a UIButton that is connected to an IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;
```

And implemented as follows:

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"submit called");
}
```

I have connected up IBActions to buttons in IB countless times and never had a problem... But for some reason this is not getting called. I hooked it up by selecting the Button->connections inspector -> touch up inside -> files owner -> submit... Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Have you tried hooking them up manually? (i.e. adding the selector programmatically?)

Comment: Please check, you might have allocated this UIButton in your code somewhere. This is one of the possible reasons. Since you are using IB, you don't need to alloc, init UIButton

Comment: i do not reference the button at all in the code... it is never even declared

Comment: You can set a background color to your scrollview to make sure it's not covering the button

Comment: Does the button show the blue highlight when you click it?

Comment: How did you declare your button? can you paste the code?

Comment: I did not declare the button in code, i just added it in IB like usual. Yes blue highlight does happen

Comment: Well, that means you button isn't covered by anything and that it's active, so it's hard to see what else could be wrong. You should double check your connection to make sure it's correct. If you did what you say you did, it should be working.

Comment: set the scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with xCode... I updated and the problem went away.

Answer (score 4):

Check Whether:

1. the owner name is correct and the touchup inside is set to the correct owner.
2. the button is getting the touch event and not covered by scrollview.
3. you are using any custom button, if yes check its implementation to see whether the touch is handled there.

Comment: for pointing out that UIButton was covered by an clear UIView

Comment: In my case, View > Interaction - User Interaction Enabled was unchecked for my UIButton. This button was copied over from another View, probably the copy/paste could have disabled "User Interaction Enabled", just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Add the UIButton instance(in your case UIView which contains the UIButton) on top of the UIScrollView.